# Automatical Truncation of Strings in @Entity JPA

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I know about annotations like

annotation `@Convert`
annotation `@Converts`
annotation `@Converter`
interface `AttributeConverter`

They are nice because I can use `@Convert` on the fields I need to convert, it's nice and elegant.

I'm looking for a similar approach for string truncation. `@Convert` doesn't fit here because I can't pass the parameter (length=10000)

Need something like

```
@Truncate(length=2000)
private String description;
```

instead of

```
public void setName(String name) {
     this.name = name.length() > 2000 ? name.substring(0,2000) : name;
}
```

because when using Lombok there will be no setters in the class

the `@Truncate(length=100)` annotation is good because I want to cut off some field automatically and do not annotate some field so that a string that is too large throws an exception.

For example

```
@Truncate(length=2000)
@Column(name = "description", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(2000)")
private String description; // want to automate a truncation

@Truncate(length=12000)
@Column(name = "description", columnDefinition = "TEXT")
private String description; // want to automate a truncation

@Column(name = "user_name", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(30)")
private String userName; // want to get an exception with to long string
```

But unfortunately, I did not find such an annotation.

Tell me if it is possible to create such an annotation. If so, how can such an approach be implemented? Thank you.

Comment: *because when using Lombok there will be no setters in the class* you can write a custom `setter` for this attribue also if you use lombok

Comment: You can also write your own AttributeConverter, which truncate the value to the length you need

Comment: @tabool  if you are on Hibernate, please check [@ColumnTransformer](https://infobrisk.com/tech-insights/how-to-use-hibernates-columntransformer-annotaion-to-format-or-modify-a-database-column-value/)

Comment: @Jens As i mentioned i can not write my own AttributeConverter because there is no possibility to pass length parameter for every field separately

Comment: But you can write a base AttributeConverter which do the trancation and inherit for every length you need

Comment: @Jens Do you mean if I have 50 different field lengths, then I need to write 50 implementations for each length? Or did I misunderstand?!

Comment: Why you need 50 different length?